# 聞いてない vs 聞いたことがない

Tags: grammar, nuances

I found this sentence

> そんなこと聞いてない!

Meaning something as "i have not heard that!"

and now im wondering, how would i change if i said:

> そんなこと聞いたことない

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～ことがある/ない describes one's experience in the past (which can be many years ago). ～ている/～ていない describes 1) one's habit, 2) the existence of the result of a previous action, and 3) an ongoing action.

- 彼はテレビを見ていない。
  He doesn't watch TV (on a regular basis). / He is not watching TV (now).
- 彼はテレビを見たことがない。
  He has never seen a TV (in his life).
- 彼女は寝ていない。
  She didn't sleep (last night, so she's sleepy).
- 彼女は寝たことがない。
  She has never had a sleep (in her entire life).
- 私はその小説を読んでいる。
  I'm a (regular) reader of that novel. / I have finished reading that novel (and remember its contents). / I'm reading that novel (now).
- 私はその小説を読んだことがある。
  I have read that novel (before).
- そんなこと聞いてない。
  No one told that (a one-time request, etc) to me (so I didn't know that).
- そんなこと聞いたことない。
  I have never heard such a thing (in my entire life).

For example, you have to say そんなこと聞いてない as a response to "So let's meet at the station at 8 tomorrow", but you have to say そんなこと聞いたことない as a response to "Don't you know penguins can fly?"

Comment: I think I'm being dumb. What does  そんなこと聞いてない mean in response to "So let's meet at the station at 8 tomorrow"?

Comment: @user3856370 - How about... *No one has told me of such a plan. Why are you giving me such short notice now?*

Answer (score 1):

I think そんなこと聞いたことない is used for common things. "I have never heard such a thing in my life.". そんなこと聞いてない is used for recent specifics things. For example, "I'm going on a trip tomorrow." -> そんなこと聞いてない!